# How to numerical sort by last column?

Tags: text-processing, sort

I have this input:

```
sdkxyosl 1
safkls 2
asdf--asdfasxy_asd 5
dkd8k  jasd 29
sdi44sw 43
asasd afsdfs 10
rklyasd 4
```

I need this output:

```
sdi44sw 43
dkd8k  jasd 29
asasd afsdfs 10
asdf--asdfasxy_asd 5
rklyasd 4
safkls 2
sdkxyosl 1
```

So i need to sort the lines by the last column.

I don't know how many columns are in one line.

I just can't figure it out, how to do it. I don't have "perl powers". I just have ~average scripting powers with sed, awk, cut, etc..

Does somebody know how to do it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The following command line uses `awk` to prepend the last field of each line of file.txt, does a reverse numerical sort, then uses `cut` to remove the added field:

```
awk '{print $NF,$0}' file.txt | sort -nr | cut -f2- -d' '
```

Comment: @forcefsck: I don't think it's possible with only `sort -k`.  The `begfield` function in GNU sort just counts down to zero.  Your decorate-sort-undecorate (DSU) approach seems to be the best way I think.

Comment: Out of interest, why `$NF,$RS` and not `$NF,$0`?  I didn't know `$RS` did that.  (I guess it's equivalent to `$NF,$"\n"`, which does the same, but that's also surprising I think.)

Comment: @johnny8888, @forcefsck: In awk, `$` can be followed by any expression. “[The effect of the field number expression evaluating to anything other than a non-negative integer is unspecified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_03)”. GNU awk (on my system) treats a string like `"\n"` as zero. Others (e.g. the original implementation by A, W and K) abort with an error message. If `RS` happened to be a digit, you'd get the corresponding field on any implementation. So don't do this, use `$0`.

Comment: Really neat!  So the long explanation of what is going on:  with awk, print the last field first then the whole record, sort in reverse numerically, then trim off the first column using cut.

Comment: The method used here is called [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: Seems not to work with negative values?

Answer (score 1):

Sort last column numerically descending with **GNU** awk:

```
awk '{
       # save current row in array with current row number as index
       row[NR]=$0

       # save current last field in array with current row number as index
       last[NR]=$NF
     }
     END{
       # sort array "last" numerically ("num") based on its
       # values ("val") descending ("desc")
       PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc";

       for(i in last)
         print row[i]
     }' file
```

As one line:

```
awk '{ row[NR]=$0; last[NR]=$NF } END{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"; for(i in last) print row[i] }' file
```

Output:

```
hello my name is Jordan: 476 
hello my name is Manu: 98
hello my name is Joi: 45
hello my name is Loi:  23 
hello my name is John:  4
```

See [8.1.6 Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) for more sorting algorithms and [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)