# Linux sort last column

Tags: shell, sort

I'm running a script (that I have no control of) to get the following output.
I want to sort by the last(3rd) column. Each column is separate by spaces, and the 2nd column includes spaces/symbols.

```
    > ./script
    37622       (this is || test1)&&(SGD||HKD||RMB)     40010
    43944       (this is)&&(SGD||HKD)    102732
    79378       (this is||test2)&&(HKD||RMB)    205425
    457000      (test2) && (SGD||RMB||HKD||YEN)        71
    559658      (test1||test2)&&(RMB||YEN||SGD)     14043
```

I tried to use sort -k, but it doesn't work.  Then I found this question - [How to numerical sort by last column?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10524/how-to-numerical-sort-by-last-column%3C/a%3E) - the solution provided is

```
awk '{print $NF,$0}' file.txt | sort -nr | cut -f2- -d' '
```

My question is: how do I make use of this when I run the script?

```
    > ./script | <something??>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Very close to what you wrote: `./script | awk '{print $NF,$0}' | sort -nr | cut -f2- -d' '`

Comment: possible duplicate of <a>http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10524/how-to-numerical-sort-by-last-column</a>

Comment: A "possible", but he actually mentions the "duplicate" question in his own question... His problem is really not related to the sort. The  issue lies in how to pass the output of his script to awk..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Awk

You can adapt the linked pipe in a straight forward way:

```
$ ./script | awk '{ print $NF,$0 }' | sort -k1,1 -n | cut -f2- -d' '
```

In `awk` the expression `$x` references the x-th column of the current line (starting with 1) - and the predefined variable `NF` stores the number of columns of the current line, thus `print $NF,$0` prints for each line the last column and the complete line (because `$0` denotes the complete line). The `cut` command then outputs the 2nd to the last column of each line.

The `-k1,1` part of sort means that only the first column is used as sort key - this only makes a difference when more than one line have the same value in the first column. Without `-k1,1` the following columns will influence the relative order (as secondary and so on sorting key) in that case. With `-k1,1` only the first column is used as sorting key - and the relative order of lines with the same key is not changed (i.e. a stable sort is performed).

### sed

Alternatively you can solve it via `sort` and `sed`:

```
$ ./script | sed 's/^\(.\+[ \t]\+\)\([0-9]\+ *\)$/\2 \1/' | \
     sort -k1,1 -n | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\) \(.\+\)$/\2 \1/'
```

Where the newline at the end of the first line is escaped via `\` - you can remove that `\` and enter the pipe as one line.

The idea is to first move the last column to the front, sort by the first column and then put it to the back again.

It is assumed that the last column is separated via white space, i.e. `[ \t]\+` (spaces or tabs).

The `sed` expressions do the swapping via group references (e.g. `\2 \1`) - the groups are marked in the pattern via escaped parentheses: `\(...\)`

Comment: What if I want the sort to happen on 3rd column?  It has the word "days=" in front of the number?  
        37622 (this is || test1)&&(SGD||HKD||RMB) days=630 40010 
        43944 (this is)&&(SGD||HKD) days=80 102732
        79378       (this is||test2)&&(HKD||RMB)     days=800 205425 

The result I'm looking for is 
        43944 (this is)&&(SGD||HKD) days=80 102732
        37622 (this is || test1)&&(SGD||HKD||RMB) days=630 40010 
        79378       (this is||test2)&&(HKD||RMB)     days=800 205425

Comment: @user11496, please post a new question - the line breaks in the comment make it hard do understand.

Comment: You are right. I've posted a new one with subject "Linux sort second last column"